# Alternative form in UpdateView

Tags: django

Can I use alternative form in UpdateView ? I mean if it created already . I tried to use 'form_class' but it has exception : " 
 **init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance**'"

`Form:
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):`

```
name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\D+$', error_messages={'invalid':'Error Name'}, label='', widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": 'Имя'}),)
surname = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\D+$', error_messages={'invalid':'Surname Name'}, label='', widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": 'Фамилия'}),)
patronymic = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\D+$', error_messages={'invalid':'Patrh Name'}, label='', widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": 'Отчество'}),)
address = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\D+$', error_messages={'invalid': 'Address incorrect'}, label='', widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": 'Массив/Улица'}), required=True)
flat = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\d+\w+$', error_messages={'invalid':'Invalid Flat'}, label='', widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": 'Квартира'}),)
home = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\d+\w+$', error_messages={'invalid':' Invalid Home'}, label='', widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": 'Дом'}),)
contact_number = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?998\d{9,15}$', error_messages={'invalid':'Номер должен начинаться с +998'}, label='', widget=forms.TextInput({"placeholder": 'Контанктный номер '}),)
prefering_connection = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
tarrif = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Profile.tarrif_plans, label='Тарифный план')`
```

`View:
 class Edit(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name = 'edit.html'`

Comment: form_class can be used. Issue must be with your form. Please update your question with your form as well.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal i did it , can you help me^_^?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a ModelForm with UpdateView not a forms.Form.

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

Comment: I am so happy , THANK YOU!